# Windows Universal Resizable Grid

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp

I have done a lot of research but many of the suggestions are outdated (WinRT), I need to allow my apps users to resize a grid horizontally and not vertically but I simply cant find a event or anything that allows this!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean resizing the complete window in a desktop environment or a user control inside the app itself?

Comment: Well I would have thought that a Grid would just be a user control, and yes a user control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

If you have this:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="100" Background="Lime"
        ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" />
```

You can do this:

```
private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    grid.Width = grid.ActualWidth + e.Delta.Translation.X;
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Best of luck!